# RTL text is not aligned correctly for iOS in react-native project

Tags: css, ios, react-native

RTL text in `<Text>` element shows aligned to left on iOS, however shows correctly on android.
`textAlign` and `direction` properties do not solve this issue

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow ! Please add a code snippet of what you have tried till now.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `writingDirection` property to text style:

`writingDirection: I18nManager.isRTL ? 'rtl' : 'ltr'`

Comment: When componenet render its not render as expected, however i refresh page then it show correctly. do you experience this issue?

Comment: @MuhammadJunaidAziz Yes you will need to use react-native-restart if direction has been changed during runtime.